# Can I use NSInvocation to hide or show a subclassed UIView without redrawing it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, nsinvocation

I am trying to use invocation to callback a `UIView` in Objective C and toggle its `hidden` property. The message must be sent to a custom view in a dedicated class `SquareView`.

For demonstration purposes my `invokerMethod` will be called from a `UIButton.` The appropriate place for this and the `SquareView` property would seem to be the `UIViewController.` But I can’t tell whether invocation is meant to return a value and my sample code gives the following error

*+[NSInvocation _invocationWithMethodSignature:frame:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'*

Can someone please point out what I have got wrong. The examples of `NSInvocation` I’ve looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313455/2348597) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4555884/2348597) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8639092/2348597) have so far not shed any light on this. And this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745768/2348597) is dead.

---

EDIT

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20039600/2348597) may be a duplicate question but the answer did not fix my problem. But I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2716143/2348597) on invocation with answers that helped produce a [simpler version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51734605/2348597) of what I am trying to do, with a slightly different problem related to the one here in this post.

---

Here is my code so far

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SquareView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView* square;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SquareView *square = [[SquareView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:square];               // draw once only

    [self.view addSubview:[self button:CGRectMake(120, 230, 100, 50)]];


    SEL selector                = @selector(invokerMethod:);
    BOOL toggle;

    UIView *target              = _square;

    NSInvocation *invocation    = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[target methodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
    invocation.selector         = selector;
    invocation.target           = target;

    [invocation setArgument:&toggle atIndex:2];
    [invocation invoke];

    __weak id returnValue       = nil;
    [invocation getReturnValue:&returnValue];
}
```

Here is the invoker method …

```
- (id)invokerMethod:(NSInteger)tag
{
    NSLog(@"toggle view each time”);
    if (_square) 
    {
        if (_square.hidden)
        {
            [_square setHidden:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [_square setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

… and here is the button method …

```
- (UIButton *)button:(CGRect)box
{
    UIButton *tap           = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:box];
    tap.backgroundColor     = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [tap setTitle:@“toggle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tap addTarget:self action:@selector(invokerMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return tap;
}
```

… and here is the view that gets toggled.

**SquareView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SquareView : UIView

@end
```

**SquareView.m**

```
#import "SquareView.h"

@implementation SquareView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self                        = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        UIView *square          = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        square.backgroundColor  = [UIColor redColor];
        [self addSubview:square];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039600/why-does-this-nsinvocation-raise-an-exception

Comment: matt, possibly but the answer there so far hasn't change my problem. I'm now looking at messaging rather than invocation, and in particular [http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_messages_as_data_type]

Comment: Well I don't see how _that's_ going to help. :)